# What is proxy in solidity why use it?

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts

What is proxy in solidity and why we use it?
I have seen about that in several documentations but I can't understand about it clearly.
Please, give me a help with an example.

Comment: Proxis are used for upgradeable contracts.

Comment: @MajdTL proxies are not used just for upgradeability. There's also the concept of a "proxy forwarder" contract, which can compose multiple Ethereum calls with DELEGATECALL. My project [PRBProxy](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-proxy) implements that.